How to add comment out multiliple lines in multiple files?
I am trying to comment out an Azure DevOps pipeline stage in multiple yaml files. I tried using

Find in Files

in Notepad++, but unsuccessful.
I am trying to comment out the following stage.
- stage: "check_code"
    jobs:
      - job: "check_code"
        pool:
          vmImage: 'windows-latest'
        steps:
          - template: check_code.yml@templates
            parameters:
              projectName: '$(projectName)'

This is what I am trying to acheive.
# - stage: "check_code"
# jobs:
  # - job: "check_code"
    # pool:
      # vmImage: 'windows-latest'
    # steps:
      # - template: check_code.yml@templates
        # parameters:
          # projectName: '$(projectName)'

When I use notepad++, I can copy the lines in the Find what search box but unable to copy the commented out multiple lines in Replace with box.

Any suggestion on how can I replace it?

Do you have other - stage:  in the files?

If you haven't, use: - Find what: ^\h* ; -Replace with: $0# 

Hi @Toto, yes I do have other stage too in the yaml file and I am trying to update it on 40 yaml files. Any suggestion?


Ctrl+H
Find what: ^(?:(- stage: "check_code"\R)|\G(\h*)(?!-stage)(.+\R))
Replace with: $2# $1$3
TICK Match case
TICK Wrap around
SELECT Regular expression
UNTICK . matches newline
Replace all

Explanation:
^                       # beginning of line
    (?:                     # non capture group
        (                       # group 1
            - stage: "check_code"   # literally
            \R                      # any kind of linebreak
        )                       # end group 1
      |                       # OR
        \G                      # restart from last match position
        (\h*)                   # group 2, 0 or more horizontal spaces
        (?!-stage)              # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't -stage after
        (                       # group 3
            .+                      # 1 or more any character
            \R                      # any kind of linebreak
        )                       # end group 3
    )                       # end group

Screenshot (before):

Screenshot (after):


Hi @Toto, Thank you. It worked for almost 60% of the files that I had to update. It didn't work for others as the check_code stage is referenced at different lines in the files, and on certain files, there was one stage with a different name.

@albbla91: Please, edit your question and add test cases with original content and expected result.
